# How to create the name of a macro programmatically and use it as a macro?

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I am using the *community-contributed* command [gvselect](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s457816.html) that permits to perform best subsets variable selection (a statistical method to select variables).

After I used it, I obtain the following result:

```
. return list

macros:
              r(best3) : " q105capitalisationboursireouvalo q12nombredefemmesauconseil q405existenceduncomitdesrmunrati"
              r(best2) : " q12nombredefemmesauconseil q405existenceduncomitdesrmunrati"
              r(best1) : " q405existenceduncomitdesrmunrati"
```

Then I need to use one of these macros in another statistical estimation method.

For example, I can use the first one as follows:

```
 xtreg  logremglobale  `r(best3)' i.date, fe
```

(note the macro `` `r(best3)' `` is used as an argument)

My framework entails that I do not know *in advance* which macro I need to use, so I determine it programmatically.

In this simplified example I may have to use `r(best1)` , `r(best2)`  or `r(best3)` (in reality there are more macros available) depending on the data.

All macros generated by [gvselect](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s457816.html) have the same syntax:   `r(best` + `number` + `)`

Once I have determined programmatically which macro I have to use (so for instance: number = 1) I'm stuck.

I don't know how to create the name of this macro programmatically and then use it as a normal macro. I'm not even sure if it is possible.

Could you help me with this ?

I have succeeded to replicate the macro name in a normal string as follows:

```
. scalar inum = 7

. gen macroname =  "r(best" + string(inum,"%8.0g")+")"

. di macroname
r(best7)
```

But how can I use it in my estimation?

Obviously the following code doesn't work:

```
xtreg  logremglobale  `macroname' i.date, fe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
sysuse auto, clear

gvselect <term> weight trunk length, nmodels(2): regress mpg <term> i.foreign

return list

scalars:
            r(nmodels) =  2
                  r(k) =  3

macros:
             r(best31) : " weight trunk length"
             r(best22) : " weight trunk"
             r(best21) : " weight length"
             r(best12) : " length"
             r(best11) : " weight"

matrices:
               r(info) :  5 x 4

scalar inum = 31
local macroname r(best`= inum')

regress price ``macroname''

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        74
-------------+----------------------------------   F(3, 70)        =     12.47
       Model |   221230614         3    73743538   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |   413834782        70  5911925.46   R-squared       =    0.3484
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.3204
       Total |   635065396        73  8699525.97   Root MSE        =    2431.4

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |   4.721599   1.132265     4.17   0.000     2.463369    6.979829
       trunk |   28.37644   97.05843     0.29   0.771    -165.2005    221.9534
      length |  -102.6652   42.58687    -2.41   0.019     -187.602   -17.72834
       _cons |   10812.33   4574.211     2.36   0.021     1689.353     19935.3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Perfect, and thank you for the detailed answer. I didn't know it was possible to create a double enclosure for a macro.